# Value 0 when IFS are not filled

Tags: google-sheets

I want to give the "draw" value 0 when the score cell is not filled - possible? Example below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vFSoq1m6VHFGkHVCGtNfObbyGTbQKNLPRegnFsBrOK0/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the conditions for empty values ​​of C and D

```
=IFS(C2="";0;D2="";0;C2=D2;1; C2<D2;0;C2>D2;0)
```

but your actual calculation can be reduced to:

```
=IF(C2=D2;1;0)
```